# How to show a limit exist in maple?

Tags: maple

Im trying to show $ \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin(\sin(2x)^2}{x^2} = 4 $ in maple, but I am not getting it. This is what I have

[image]

Comment: $$\frac{{\sin (\sin {{(2x)}^2})}}{{{x^2}}} = \frac{{\sin (\sin {{(2x)}^2})}}{{\sin {{(2x)}^2}}}\frac{{\sin {{(2x)}^2}}}{{{x^2}}} = 4\frac{{\sin (\sin {{(2x)}^2})}}{{\sin {{(2x)}^2}}}\frac{{\sin {{(2x)}^2}}}{{{{\left( {2x} \right)}^2}}}$$

Comment: Your "Error" comes because $x$ is symbolic in the comparison.  Maybe you mean $\delta$.  Also, if you want error $10^{-10}$ you should increase *Digits* to something higher than $10$.

Comment: I change $x$ for $\delta$, but it is not printing

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to modify the condition, it should be $|f - 4| > \epsilon $

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't be that hard.  Maple has a "limit" command  Try something like `limit((sin(sin(2*x)))^2/x^2,x=0);`

You miscounted your parentheses so I'm guessing what you meant and I don't guarantee I counted them right, but that's how you do it.

Comment: @Citizen : I didn't read your epsilon-delta scheme in the Maple code because you can easily find the limit without it.  If you want to get it to work and you can't, you might try posting your question on the discussion forum at mapleprimes.com .  You should get a good answer within hours.  Please note that you can and should upload your Maple code so people know exactly what you tried.